# WP Query for all posts

Tags: pagination, archives

I have page-property.php in the loop folder with this code. And I see only 8 posts (Custom Post type), but I want to see all of them with pagination, what's wrong?

```
<?php   

 $view = 'archive';
   if ( is_singular() )
$view = 'single';
 elseif ( is_search() )
$view = 'search';
 elseif ( is_404() )
$view = '404';

 if ( Pojo_Compatibility::is_bbpress_installed() && is_bbpress() )
$view = 'page';

 do_action( 'pojo_setup_body_classes', $view, get_post_type(), '' );

  get_header();

 do_action( 'pojo_get_start_layout', $view, get_post_type(), '' );
   ?>

  <header>
            <?php if ( po_breadcrumbs_need_to_show() ) : ?>
                <?php pojo_breadcrumbs(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( pojo_is_show_page_title() ) : ?>
                <div class="page-title">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </header>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

 <?php

 global $_pojo_parent_id, $custom_query;


   $_pojo_parent_id = get_the_ID();
   $pagination = atmb_get_field( 'po_pagination' );
   $display_type = po_get_display_type();

  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array ( 'post_type' => 'property', 'post_per_page' => 8, 'paged' => $paged );

  $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
 ?>
```

```
        <?php if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'pojo_before_content_loop', $display_type ); ?>
            <?php while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php pojo_get_content_template_part( 'content', $display_type ); ?>

            <?php endwhile;
             ?>
            <?php do_action( 'pojo_after_content_loop', $display_type ); ?>
            <?php  if ( 'hide' !== $pagination ) : ?>
                <?php pojo_paginate( ); ?>
            <?php endif;  ?>
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', '' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php pojo_button_post_edit(); ?>
```

Comment: what is the full code of the function `pojo_paginate( )` ? this function might not work with a custom query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the URL https://nadlancz.com/page/2/ you'll see that navigation works.

What you need to do to see the navigation links is add something like this to your page

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<?php
    $pagination = get_the_posts_pagination(array(
       'mid_size' => 2,
       'prev_text' => 'Previous',
       'next_text' => 'Next',
    ));

    if (defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        $pagination = reformat_ajax_pagination($pagination);
    }

    echo $pagination;
?>
```

Comment: please be aware that https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_posts_pagination/ only works on the default query, not custom queries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be a number of things.

First of all, make sure you have more than 8 posts. If you do, then make sure you're pagination is working properly (numbered nav links to different pages should show up on page).

Some more information would be helpful to better answer you question. Maybe a screenshot of the rendered page?

Comment: I have more than one post, but I don't see pagination at all. Here is the page: https://nadlancz.com/ It is front page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all! I was needed to add parameter to  `pojo_paginate()`:

```
pojo_paginate( $custom_query )
```